# Chatroom reply highlighting bug

Tags: bug, status-deferred, chat

Earlier today I found a bug in the chatroom, where a pinged message will stay highlighted it is being highlighted while the ping is removed. Steps to reproduce:

1. Join any chatroom.
2. Ping someone in a message, using `@user`.
3. Click `edit` on that message, and delete the ping from the message. *Don't save the edit yet!*
4. Move the mouse over your message (where it appears in the message pane), so the previous message by the pinged user is highlighted in grey.
5. Press Enter.
6. Move your mouse all around the screen, and observe the original pinged message continue to be highlighted grey.
7. Ping the same user or reload the page to fix the highlighting.

This bug is not very important, but it would be nice if it were fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Highlighting is completely barked, there are many more bugs with it.